# Reconstructing the original geometry of an object by using negativ and positiv buffers

Tags: geometry, buffer

I have serveral objects with a "thin" geometry which are connected by a very slim passage.

[image]

My goal is to remove this connection so the object is devided into two separeted features. My idea to achieve this was to first apply a negativ buffer with -0.5 m and afterwards a postive buffer with +0.5 m again so the object gets "reshaped" but the splitting line from the buffer keeps preserved.

This is how the geometry looks with the negaitv buffer

[image]

But when I try to reconstruct the original geometry by using a positive buffer with the negativ buffer as the input it does not work. The original geometry is not rebuild but it just gets some "round corners".

[image]

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3. In the buffer function I tried both methods, "PLANAR" and "GEODESIC" but nothing works unfortunately.

Has anyone have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: With QGIS, this would be possible using join-style `bevel` or `miter`

Comment: Just speculating but if you run the Integrate tool and try different tolerances (use copies as inputs since the tool changes the input instead of producing a new layer) these may produce "bow tie" polygons which aren't usually desirable.  Then you might run the multipart to singlepart to split them.  Check/repair your geometry after.